# Rotating letters by a fixed number of places [python programming]

Tags: python, rotation

I am new to python programming and would like to write a program which has the following requirement:

The program accepts an input string and the number of rotations. Rotate all characters in the string and print the result on screen.

For example, input is ABCDZ 3
Then,
output is DEFGC

```
def rotate(input,d): 

Rfirst = input[0 : len(input)-d] 
Rsecond = input[len(input)-d : ] 

print "Right Rotation : ", (Rsecond + Rfirst)
```

However, I have written a few codes by myself and turned out that I could only rotate the character within ABCDZ to e.g. ZABCD instead of the rotation pattern dictated in the requirement.

Would anyone like to give help on the issue? How should I start with the correct direction? Thank you very much to all of you. I am really frustrated..

Comment: please show us your attempt with a [mcve]

Comment: Have a look at [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).

Comment: @depperm I have edited : ) Please have a check if possible.

Comment: @ChristianKönig I am trying to get the idea...

Comment: In your example you "shift" the letters, so a->d, b->e... In your code, you change positions of the letters in your input. Decide what you want to do.

Comment: What's the logic behind the conversion from `ABCDZ` to `ZABCD` ?

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
def rotate_str(mstr, n):
  reverse = False
  if n < 0:
    n, reverse = - n, True
  for _ in range (0,n):
    if not reverse: mstr = mstr[-1] + mstr[0:-1]
    if reverse: mstr = mstr[1:] + mstr[0]
  return mstr
```

Negative `n` reverses the direction of rotation.

```
mstr = 'ABCDZ'
print(rotate_str(mstr, 3)) #=> CDZAB
print(rotate_str(mstr, -4)) #=> ZABCD
```